# Getting value from textbox and storing it in a variable in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, textbox, userform

I am trying to make an application to get the data from the textbox and store it in a variable for further uses thou I am getting value of it as 0 . Anyone can help out?

```
Dim value As Long

value = Val(password.output.Caption)
game.Caption = value
```

In the above code password is my form name and output is the name of field from where it shall get data and then later it is changing the value of game field to the value fetched of output and I am getting 0 as the value . What to do guys? Any help will be appreciated

### **UPDATE**

I would actually like to retrieve the string any idea how to do it?

Comment: Is this a userform in Excel or a form within Access?

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve number from password.output.Caption? Because Val function returns the numbers contained in string, else it returns 0.

Comment: Actually I wanna retrieve string . Any ideas how could I do it? I am new to vba

Comment: Try this.  `Dim value = password.output.Caption`

Comment: Nope this does not works for me

Comment: Thanks now its working :D

Comment: If that line of code is working (I'm pretty skeptic), it isn't really clean one, because you declare and assign a value at the same...

Answer (score 3):

Val function returns the numbers contained in string, else it returns 0.

Try this.

```
 Dim value As String
 value = password.output.Caption
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go :

```
Dim ValuePw As String

ValuePw = Password.output.Value
Password.game.Value = ValuePw
```

`.Caption` is used for *Labels' content* and *UserForms' title*, for *TextBoxes' content*, it is `.Value`